# Twitter bootstrap limiting collapsed dropdown menu width

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

In Twitter Bootstrap 3 I have collapsed dropdown in my navbar.
For `ul` classes I put them left and right like this:

```
   <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-aaa1" id="id1">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-left">
            <li><a href="">Link left 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Link left 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Link left 3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-bbb1" id="id2">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
            <li><a href="">Link right 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Link right 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Link right 3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
```

But it seems like dropdown menu has full width. But I need dropdown width to auto. I mean, width will be adequate fr links to be one line, but each line doesn't get all width. It should have as minimum width as it can.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mavent/TXK8T/9/

**Current state:**

[image]

**I need this:**

[image]

**I need this:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this?

First we take `.navbar-aaa1` and `.navbar-bbb1` out of the normal flow of the document so it won't add height to the `navbar`.

Then we need to add some background color and set position relativly to `navbar` (since it's `position: relative` out of the box in Bootstrap). Note I used `-1px` because `navbar` has border of 1px width set.

```
.navbar-aaa1, .navbar-bbb1 {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #222;
    border: 1px solid #080808;
}

.navbar-aaa1 {
    left: -1px;
}

.navbar-bbb1 {
    right: -1px;
}
```

Last, we should set positioning back to static using media query for bigger screens (since Bootstrap3 is mobile first).

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .navbar-aaa1, .navbar-bbb1 {
        position: static;
        border: none;
    }
}
```

Take a look here: http://jsfiddle.net/TXK8T/11/